# CSS stretch parent div to max height of overlaid children

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am overlaying some title text on an image, currently using relative/absolute position for one of the elements (doesn't matter which). What I am struggling with is getting the parent div to fully display the content of both, irrespective of which is taller.

Example markup:

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px; /* This is only here to force the title text in this example to expand beyond the image height for illustrative purposes. */
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
}

.title-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img class="background" src="http://www.placebacon.net/200/200">
    <div class="title-text">
        My Title (which might be quite long)
    </div>
<div>
```

(Assuming I can acheive what I am looking for, the `overflow: hidden` above would obviously become redundant, but presently without it, the taller element overlaps whatever is below the parent div.)

JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/yixiniwere/edit?html,css,output

How do I get both elements to be fully visible? I can change the mark-up or introduce additional container elements if necessary.

Comment: Might make most sense if you applied this image as a background-image to begin with (or is it actual _content_?) - then you can use background-size to have it adapt to the container size. The text would of course not be absolutely positioned then. You can throw in a min-height you want it to cover in cases where the text would be extremely short.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I understand that, which is why I said 'Current CSS'. I don't really care what CSS rules are needed - I just want the content to display correctly.

Comment: @CBRoe - the image is content rather than just background filler - perhaps using the classname 'background' was a poor choice in that respect.

Comment: @CBroe has the right idea. Your code is telling you to use a background image (you have given it the class `background`). Listen to it. And then you can remove the `position: absolute` on the title and the parent will naturally be the height (along with the `min-height`, as suggested, for super short titles).

Comment: @Adam, if I use background-image to present the image in question, I can't ensure the full image is displayed. Setting any explicit height or min-height values is not a suitable solution either.

Comment: @JohnRix - you can if you fit the image to the container using `background-size: contain`. Image sizes are hard enough on the web, I've found that scaling them by using them as background images is by far the easiest way to get a consistent and nice layout. You will, too.

Comment: Yes, except I want the image to fill the width of the parent container (hence the width: 100% on the styling in my question).

Comment: @JohnRix - fine, then use `background-size: cover` (that's actually what I use everywhere in these types of overlay layouts). It ends up cropping part of your image, but it usually produces a far nicer effect than `background-size: contain` which leaves dead space. You have to take my (and @CBroe) word for it, there is not an easier way to achieve the effect you want than simply using a `background-image`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use that either. I REALLY don't want to crop the image in any way. At this point, I have successfully implemented @Paulie_D's solution using CSS Grid and found the IE tweaks needed to make it work there also.

Comment: Just to be clear, I do appreciate all the input from everybody here! This has been a good discussion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overlay elements *without* using positioning under CSS-Grid. You just assign them the same place in the grid.

```css
.parent {

  /* IE10/11 support */
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;

  margin: 1em auto;
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  /* for demo purposes */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  background: pink;
}

.parent * {

  /* IE10/11 support */
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;

  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="background" src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/200">
  <div class="title-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rerum perspiciatis commodi, adipisci reiciendis quo suscipit! Ratione laborum magnam cumque tempora ab cupiditate delectus, perferendis enim porro impedit nihil architecto, ad consequatur exercitationem
    fugiat error debitis molestias itaque, eligendi necessitatibus quae dolore beatae nemo doloremque. Quos voluptate tenetur explicabo beatae nesciunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo est perspiciatis possimus iusto! Voluptatem
    facilis blanditiis aspernatur facere animi placeat. Quisquam fuga laudantium cupiditate eos exercitationem neque eius, distinctio consectetur?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis aperiam, ipsum tempora reiciendis, id ea
    eveniet placeat necessitatibus deserunt mollitia dignissimos exercitationem aliquam porro quaerat, labore ducimus rerum animi praesentium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, laboriosam.
    <div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that... was wondering if CSS Grid might come into play here. Have not used it to date. Is there a workable fall-back option for the likes of IE though?

Comment: Grid is supported by IE (in some flavours) but it might require prefixing. Other than that there are few options other than positioning which has it's own issues.

Comment: Got it working, thanks! Have edited answer to include additional IE specific elements I needed to make it work there also.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to get rid of relative and absolute positioning and only set the 'margin-top' property of the text to the negative value of the background. Example (if the icon has fixed height of 100px you can just set margin top of title-text to -100px):

```
.parent {
    width: 150px;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
}

.title-text {
    margin-top:-100px;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

if the height of the background in not fixed you should be able to get it via javascript and set it there.

[js bin example](http://jsbin.com/yisuheniye/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Yeah, that would work if I had fixed height images. Sadly, that's not the case though.

Comment: You could also set the margin in js (get the background element height value and set the margin of title-text elemen(s) to that value but negated). But even though it's not very complicated, it's not a good practice and the grid element seems way better if the height is not fixed.

Answer (score -1):

The non css grid/flexboxy way

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #a03;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.title-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="background" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472837525377-e96df4f8f34e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=b29757bb040fca6a9b0d79cbd31f1119">
  <div class="title-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rerum perspiciatis commodi, adipisci reiciendis quo suscipit! Ratione laborum magnam cumque tempora ab cupiditate delectus, perferendis enim porro impedit nihil architecto, ad consequatur exercitationem fugiat error debitis molestias itaque, eligendi necessitatibus quae dolore beatae nemo doloremque. Quos voluptate tenetur explicabo beatae nesciunt! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo est perspiciatis possimus iusto! Voluptatem facilis blanditiis aspernatur facere animi placeat. Quisquam fuga laudantium cupiditate eos exercitationem neque eius, distinctio consectetur?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis aperiam, ipsum tempora reiciendis, id ea eveniet placeat necessitatibus deserunt mollitia dignissimos exercitationem aliquam porro quaerat, labore ducimus rerum animi praesentium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, laboriosam.
    <div>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: This overlaps any content below it unfortunately.

Comment: Let me look at it again. That last comment adds to the picture.

Comment: Was not me that down-voted it by the way. My original question does allude to not overlapping content below though.

Comment: No worries. I like the challenge